# Restrict body (min-width) width in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't want my app resizing and responding to sizes lower than a given width... say 600px.

I can't just do `body { min-width: 600px }` in Bootstrap because of media queries.

What can I do instead?

Answer (score 4):

You could always adjust the media queries.

Try this:

```
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
body {background:#c00;min-width:600px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</body>
```

And then reset/edit/override all the other elements inside this media query.

Comment: How would you adjust the media queries?  I'd like to avoid modifying the bootstrap source if I can.  I'm happy to augment it with my own overrides, however.

Comment: Place new css with adjusted media queries (just copy the existing queries and modify them to suit your needs) below the original css?

Comment: I understand that.  Can you give an example of new media queries that will do this?  Which queries do I need to change?  How do I change them?

Comment: also if you using navbar add to media querie `#mainNav {position: static;}`

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the disabling responsiveness section in the BS docs: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Maybe you can do something like this:

http://bootply.com/92061

Comment: I want it to be responsive, but only to a certain size.  Once it gets to be a certain width, I want it to stop being responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try recompiling bootstrap with different media query size. If you are not using less in your project, try using their [customize page](https://getbootstrap.com/customize/).

For example, if you want to set your body with min-width of 600px and still perverse the responsiveness of the larger screen.

1. Compile bootstrap with

   ```
   @screen-xs: 0px;
   @screen-sm: 1px;
   ```
2. Add this to your css file

   ```
   body {
       min-width: 600px;
   }
   ```